# How to get the first parent that has a certain CSS property using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I need to get the first parent that has `position:relative`. Something like in the example below but my real content will be dynamically generated.

```
<div id="parent1" style="position:relative">
    <div id="parent2">
        <div id="my-element" style="position:absolute"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do you know a simple way to do this using jQuery?

Comment: The [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) is a great place to get all informations you need.

Comment: @Doorknob - I have searched for a similar answer but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @yckart - I believe that recommending to read the documentation is not the purpose of this site...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can `filter` the set of `parents()`, and grab the first element matching your filter:

```
$('#my-element')
    .parents()
    .filter(function() { 
        return $(this).css('position') == 'relative'; 
    }).first();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AEmjH/) ([Works with classes, too](http://jsfiddle.net/AEmjH/1/))

Comment: Thank you David, very quick answer! It is great that it is working with classes too.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend you to add a class instead of changing directly the style and then looking for that class using jQuery. Is much more simple and intuitive.

CSS:

```
.active{
    position:relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="parent1" class="active">
    <div id="parent2">
        <div id="my-element"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
//getting the first element with .active class
$('#my-element').closest('.active')
```

Comment: This might very well be a good approach, but I'd imagine "first parent" is to be interpreted as closest parent. You're just fetching the first element, regardless of whether or not it is a parent. You might consider something like `$('#my-element').closest('.active')`