# Get element constraint

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working recently with very nested HTML elements. Sometimes, an element's size is constrained by a parent element several levels up, or more. Finding the constraint can be tough.

An example is that I want a video to scale with the screen size, but past about 1200 pixels in width the height maxes out. After spending twenty minutes combing through the parent layers in the inspector, I find that six layers up on a parent div, at the bottom of the list of that div's rules, is a max-height constraint. Now I can continue working.

Is there a faster way to find the rule that is constraining an element? I'd love a jquery method like $('element').nearestHeightConstraint() or something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the first parent that has a certain CSS property using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202542/how-to-get-the-first-parent-that-has-a-certain-css-property-using-jquery)

Comment: The above question/answer should solve your issue if you use "max-height" as the CSS property in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for max-height:

```
$.fn.nearestHeightConstraint = function(){
    if(parseInt(this.css('max-height'))){
        return this.css('max-height');
    }else{
        var p = this.parent();
        if(this.nodeType != 'body' && p.length){
            return p.nearestHeightConstraint();
        }else{
            return null; // not found
        }
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/anxhwvv7/

Comment: Thank you, this works. The referenced question had a more succinct answer already, but thanks for responding.

Comment: Yeah, both work, mine deals with recursion that might hit too much recursion, the other method picks all parents and then filters them, so can hit more memory usage and it might be slower. Still, with 1-20 parent layer there shouldn´t be any difference. Feel free to use any and good luck with proyect